# Animate recycler view items left-right to tell user of swipe options

Tags: android, android-animation, android-recyclerview

I have implemented a gesture to hint user of the swipe options that we have in our iOS app. Its looking like-

[image]

I am new to Android app development. I have implemented everything like the screen except the animation. How do I add same animation in Android application for recycler view items?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I implemented it myself.

Here is `item_layout.xml`-

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/leftView"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/main_layout"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/main_layout"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:background="@color/darkGray" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/rightView"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/main_layout"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/main_layout"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:background="@color/darkRed" />

    <RelativeLayout id="@+id/main_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        ...
    </RelativeLayout>    

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the `RecyclerView.Adapter` implementation-

```
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_layout, parent, false);

    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    ....
    ....

    if (position == 0) {
        ObjectAnimator animationLeft = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(holder.swipeLayout, "translationX", 0f, 80f, 0f, -80f, 0f);
        animationLeft.setDuration(1500);
        animationLeft.start();
    }
}
```

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: The only problem with this is that the animation might be called before the view was drawn.

Comment: I am not sure when this can happen. Did you notice that? In my case it's still working well. Why makes you say that? I may update the method in such case.

Comment: When loading data from a server, it takes a few milliseconds to get the data and populate the view. When I, for example, set it to `if (position == 4) {`, then the animation works.

Comment: Ohh, I can see now. But I don't think getting data in onBindViewHolder is a good idea. Is that what you are referring to?

Comment: In my case, I got the date from server on load, created the list from response object, that list is being used to populate the adapter. Now, for each item in list, onBindViewHolder will be called and it will return the populated ViewHolder. Right after completion of the binding, animation will start.

Comment: Yup I have the same. The data is retrieved before I set the adapter, stored in an `ArrayList` using a POJO class and then read in `onBindViewHolder`. Come to think of it, the animation should be loading because by the time the view binds, the data is already available. I will do some checks to see where the delay might come from.

Comment: I found the cause. My `RecyclerView` is in reverse order using layout manager `layoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);`. So `if (position == 0) {` will be called on the last item. So instead I'm using `if (position == myList.size()-1) {` and now I see the animation. Silly mistake. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Thumbs up!! Cheers!! Good for you :)

Comment: @PankajDubey what is `swipeLayout` here ?

Comment: It's been long since I worked on this, In my holder implementation, I think I used a variable of RelativeLayout type which I named swipelayout.

RelativeLayout swipeLayout =   <RelativeLayout id="@+id/main_layout">