# User tips in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I know how to swipe to delete an item in the RecyclerView. I would like to know how to implement a hint to the user that there is such a possibility? That is, slightly shift any of the elements and return it to its place.

Comment: Try this: [Animate RecyclerView items left-right to tell the user of swipe options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59526015/animate-recycler-view-items-left-right-to-tell-user-of-swipe-options)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, then this library is very useful to the user, Where it is suitable to informing about the hidden feature.

[ShowcaseView](https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView):

```
     ViewTarget target = new ViewTarget(R.id.buttonBlocked, this);
            sv = new ShowcaseView.Builder(this)
                    .withMaterialShowcase()
                    .setTarget(target)
                    .setContentTitle(R.string.showcase_main_title)
                    .setContentText(R.string.showcase_main_message)
                    .setStyle(R.style.CustomShowcaseTheme2)
                    .setShowcaseEventListener(this)
                    .replaceEndButton(R.layout.view_custom_button) //Add your Recyclerview item root layout id
                    .build();
            sv.setButtonPosition(lps);
```

[image]

[MaterialIntroView](https://github.com/iammert/MaterialIntroView):

```
new MaterialIntroView.Builder(this)
                .enableDotAnimation(true)
                .enableIcon(false)
                .setFocusGravity(FocusGravity.CENTER)
                .setFocusType(Focus.MINIMUM)
                .setDelayMillis(500)
                .enableFadeAnimation(true)
                .performClick(true)
                .setInfoText("Hi There! Click this card and see what happens.")
                .setShapeType(ShapeType.CIRCLE)
                .setTarget(view)
                .setUsageId("intro_card") //THIS SHOULD BE UNIQUE ID
                .show();
```

[image]

Comment: Not the answer to the question

Comment: How is this an answer? The user requested a way to programmatically swipe/animate an item in a RecyclerView to demonstrate the swipe option.

Comment: @gioravered he clear mentioned `I would like to know how to implement a hint to the user that there is such a possibility? `

Comment: And continued with: "That is, slightly shift any of the elements and return it to its place."

Comment: Call him and ask him the for the clarification